# Как поменять спрайт в Game maker 2

Tags: разработка-игр, спрайт, game-maker, gml

У меня есть три спрайта, Персонаж садится, персонаж встает, персонаж сидит, ну и два спрайта как он стоит (один просто вправо повернут другой влево). Первый и второй спрайты не цикличные, просто промежуточная анимация. Как можно реализовать, чтобы он сначала садился, а потом сидел (по одноразовому нажатию кнопки). Повторное нажатие — и он вставал.

Пробовал без промежуточных анимаций, просто в положение сидя сразу. В **Step** сделал `keyboard_check_released(ord("E"))`, но так не работает совсем. С обычным `keyboard_check` работало, но только если зажимать, а мне не надо так. С промежуточными анимациями вообще не представляю как сделать…

Comment: Можно пример вашего кода на gml?